# How to check if a message is really delivered in Netty using websocket?

Tags: java, websocket, timeout, client-server, netty

I'm developing a websocket application by using Netty. I'd like to know if a message is really delivered from a source to a destination. In particular, let's assume that a client and a server have an open channel and exchange some messages for a while. At a certain point, the client goes down, but the channel is still active in Netty. I tried to use isReachable() before sending the message, but this method seems to be buggy in some scenarios (e.g. a machine with Win7 is up, but isReachable() returns false). Now, my idea is to implement a mechanism using ACKs, namely the server sends the message and the client sends back an ack. To do that, I need a timeout to see if, after a certain interval, the corresponding ack does not arrive. Is there something similar in Netty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding isReachable() - it's only a best effort API. The documentation points out that it tries to send an ICMP echo request or create a TCP connection to port 7 on the destination host, both of which are highly likely to be blocked by a firewall. Is this happening in your case?

As for the acknowledgement, there's nothing in Netty that provides this as standard, but it shouldn't be too difficult to implement. Firstly each message needs to be uniquely identifible by some sort of identifier, possibly a sequence number but a globally unique identifier means you can potentially recover across disconnections. Then you want to create a combined handler that implements both ChannelInboundHandler and ChannelOutboundHandler (assuming Netty 4). When a message is sent

- add the message to a map indexed by its id
- create a timer associated with the message id. Add it to another map indexed by message id
- forward the message

When the ACK is received cancel the timer and remove the timer and message from their respective maps. If the timer fires use the associated id to decide what to do with the timer and message (possibly retransmit and reset the timer).

Netty provides a HashedWheelTimer for efficiently managing lots of timers with a resolution suitable for this kind of activity.

You may also want to consider putting a limit on the number of retries so you can stop and raise an error rather than continually indefinitely.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, johnstir. Win7 replies to ping requests if the command is executed by a shell, but not by java. For that reason, I said it might be a little buggy.
I'm not sure if this could be "too much" for my software. It's like a chat, so it forwards a lot of messages and the software should contain many many timers. Ok, let's suppose for a moment that my software tries to do its best with no ACK, but what if it only wants to check the client still connected before sending a message? Which alternatives do we have to isReachable()?

Comment: Ok, my problem is the same of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677864/netty-writeandflush-with-future-is-successfull-to-killed-host

You replied to that, too! :)

Comment: I should just emphasise that isReachable() isn't really suited for your needs. I hope you've found an answer but on the point about having lots of timers, this is usually dealt with by restricting the amount of messages you can have outstanding at any one time. So for example you send 10 messages and put them in a queue (called a send window), and leave the others queued in some other data structure. When a message is ACK'd you remove it from the send window and send another message from your other queue, thus filling the send window again. This limits the outstanding messages and timers.